# Correct Inno Setup script generated by Script Wizard to avoid duplicating main executable from a subfolder into the root folder

Tags: inno-setup

I have a folder named `xyz`, where I have other files / folders.
My main exe is in `xyz/app/main.exe`.
I would like to add whole content of `xyz` and create shortcut to `main.exe` in a desktop.

The problem is that, when I select `main.exe` as a main executable file, add whole folder `xyz` and install it I get whole content `xyz` folder and additional `main.exe` (`pathToInstall/main.exe`). So I have two `main.exe`:

- `pathToInstall/main.exe`
- `pathToInstall/app/main.exe`

The shortcut in a desktop is to `pathToInstall/main.exe`.

I would like to have only one `main.exe` in `pathToInstall` and shortcut should be to `pathToInstall/app/main.exe`

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the `[Files]` section manually.

Keep just the entry that installs the folder. Remove the entry that installs the `.exe`.